# NAT in L3 CISCO switches?

Tags: cisco, switch, nat

I wonder if L3 CISCO switch can also perform NAT.

In my proyect, I have 5 subnets that I need to route (and also provide internet access), and it is said to me that routers with many interfaces are expensive.

Is there a better (cost-effective) solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably, but depends on the switch model and sw version.

Comment: Could you recommend one of them?

Comment: Product recommendations are, sadly, off-topic on this forum.

Comment: How much traiiffic is there likely to be between the different internal subnets? how much traffic is there likely to be to/from the Internet.

Comment: Just a few Mbps. Intenal subnets ~15 Mbps in total. From Internet, just to use Teamviewer, and ocassionally web access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we're talking about Cisco, there are some switches that can do NAT but all of them are really not cheap, even by Cisco standards. Better and definalely cheaper solution is to do it like most of people are doing - get a switch and a router (or some of the Cisco ISR routers that have integrated switch in them). Besides it's cheaper, you will have much more features at your disposal.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, only Cisco 6K series switches can do NAT. Cisco claims that you need hardware to do NAT, and the hardware is not included in Cisco switches. The 6K switches are EoS, but there are replacements, and I'm not sure any of those can do NAT. I do know that none of the 2K, 3K, or 4K switches can do NAT.

Comment: True for the Catalysts but a number of the Nexus line can support NAT - notably the 3500 and many of the 9K's.  It's more special-purpose and definitely has a bunch of limitations when compared to an ISR/ASR.  The 7K can also do destination NAT (used in the context of ITD), but this wouldn't hit the described use-case in the question.